# Code changes not pushing as expected

Tags: git, github, push

I updated a CSS file. It shows as changed when using:

```
git status
```

[image]

Then i call: `git add/build/public/css/base.css`

Then when I `git push`

I get that the file is up to date and GitHub hasn't been changed:

[image]

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is because you also need to commit your change:

```
git commit -m "added base.css"
```

After you make your commit, run your push command.

`git push` will only push committed changes, and staging (add) is just for building up commits.

Also (might be just a typo in your question) but make sure you have a space after your "add" and give it a path relative to your pwd:

```
git add build/public/css/base.css
```

Answer (score 2):

1. `git add <file>` e.g `git add build/public/css/base.css` for all the files you want to add
2. `git commit -a -m "message goes here..."`
3. `git push`
   this shall solve it.

Comment: It's bad to get in the habbit of `git add .`, I wouldn't recommend it to others.

Answer (score 1):

The steps are as follows:

1. git add .
2. git commit -m "commit message"
3. git push

If you wish to only commit certain files then your step 1 would be

1. git add file.txt